# How to setup Nginx with Varnish

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, varnish, ruby, ruby-rack

**I'd like to see how to configure Nginx and Varnish.**

I'm running several PHP sites and Rack-Sinatra sites as virtual hosts across two IP's.
I'd like to prevent Nginx from having to serve static files, since I'm noticing some delays.

***Edit***: I've changed to Nginx, but the answer provided is pretty easy to port over to nginx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache will still serve static files, but it will only serve them *once*.  Perhaps the easiest way is to configure varnish to listen on all IP addresses for port 80, and configure Apache to listen to on `localhost:8000` for example.  Then you configure varnish to forward all requests it receives to `localhost:8000` for Apache to handle.

I would go with a varnish configuration of:

```
# have varnish listen on port 80 (all addresses)
varnishd -a 0.0.0.0:80
```

Now within your `vcl` file:

```
backend default {
  .host = "localhost";
  .port = "8000";
}

sub vcl_recv {
  # add a unique header containing the client IP address
  set req.http.X-Orig-Forwarded-For = client.ip;

  # we're only handling static content for now so remove any
  # Cookie that was sent in the request as that makes caching
  # impossible.
  if (req.url ~ "\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|js|css)(\?.*|)$") {
    unset req.http.cookie;
  }
}

vcl_fetch {
  # if the backend server adds a cookie to all responses,
  # remove it from static content so that it can be cached.
  if (req.url ~ "\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico|js|css)(\?.*|)$") {
    unset obj.http.set-cookie;
  }
}
```

Now within your Apache `httpd.conf` configuration, you want Apache to listen on `localhost:8000` and define your virtual hosts on the same address:port

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8000
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8000
```

For each website, create a `<VirtualHost>` stanza.  Within that stanza you need to tell Apache to set the `Expires` and cache-control headers on all static content so varnish knows to cache it.

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8000>
  ServerName www.our-example-domain.com

  # Set expires and cache-control headers on static content and
  # tell caches that the static content is valid for two years
  ExpiresActive on

  <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|ico|gif|png|jpe?g)$">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 year"
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
  </FilesMatch>

  # ... the rest of your web site configuration ...
</VirtualHost>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: dude — this looks awesome! I'm at work right now, but I'll try this and accept it when I get home.

Comment: Although I no longer use Apache — nginx is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of future readers, for the VCL example provides by rjk:

- I'd use "remove" instead of "unset" for the HTTP cookie variable.
- The subroutine declaration 'vcl_fetch {' should be written as 'sub vcl_fetch {', too.

Otherwise, spot on. :)

Comment: why is remove better than unset — does unset send a blank cookie or something?

Comment: Because unset isn't supported anymore AFAIK.